# cannot include roots in play framework

Tags: routes, playframework

I have created a module called design inside /var/www/html/play-1.2.2/modules/design
I have my play application in /var/www/html/MyPlayApp

In MyPlayApp dependencies.yml i have given

```
require:
    - play
    - play -> design
```

In MyPlayApp routes i have given

```
GET     /design                                 module:design.index
```

I have created index page inside the design module

In Design.java in controllers

```
package controllers;

import models.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import java.util.*;
import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.*;

public class Design extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }
}
```

Inside design controllers dependencies.yml

```
self: play -> design 0.1
require:
    - play
```

Inside design module routes

```
GET     /                                       Design.index
```

When i run the application and enter into the browser it says

```
10:03:41,114 ERROR ~ Cannot include routes for module design.index
```

Please help out of this........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your app route:

```
GET     /design                                 module:design
```

and this in your module route:

```
GET     /?                                       Design.index
```

this should redirect /design to your module and in the module, by default, everything will go to index.